# Zip can't be opened with Go because of incorrect mime from server

Tags: http, go, http-headers, mime

I have an application that sends a zip file to a server. The zip is then manipulated and a new zip is send back in the response.

The problem is that the response sent back has a mime of `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/zip` message.

I think this is the reason why the resulting zip can't be opened by `archive/zip` and I get a `zip: not a valid zip file`.

Is there any way for me to change the mime when retrieving the zip file?

My code for getting the zip:

```
func GetZipFromServer(zipname string) {

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Open local zip file

    file, err := os.Open(zipname + ".zip")
    log1.Check(err, "File open failed")
    defer file.Close()

    stat, err := file.Stat()
    log1.Check(err, "Stat failed")

    fmt.Println(stat.Size())

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Get new zip from server

    url := "http://some_server123.com/rest/"
    res, err := http.Post(url, "application/zip", file)
    log1.Check(err, "Response failed")

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Save new zip from server as file

    f, err := os.Create(zipname + ".html.zip")
    log1.Check(err, "Cannot create file")

    err = res.Write(f)
    log1.Check(err, "Cannot write file")

    err = f.Close()
    log1.Check(err, "Cannot close file")
}
```

Comment: You'd need to set the header while **processing** the `.zip` on the server.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this if I don't have access to the server?

Comment: Unfortunately not; the mime must be set server-side.

Comment: This problem is unrelated to the value of the Content-Type response header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Response.Write](https://godoc.org/net/http#Response.Write) method writes the response in server response format to the argument.  That's not what you want.

Use [io.Copy](https://godoc.org/io#Copy) to copy the response body to the file:

```
func GetZipFromServer(zipname string) {
    file, err := os.Open(zipname + ".zip")
    log1.Check(err, "File open failed")
    defer file.Close()

    stat, err := file.Stat()
    log1.Check(err, "Stat failed")

    fmt.Println(stat.Size())

    url := "http://some_server123.com/rest/"
    res, err := http.Post(url, "application/zip", file)
    log1.Check(err, "Response failed")

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    f, err := os.Create(zipname + ".html.zip")
    log1.Check(err, "Cannot create file")

    _, err := io.Copy(f, resp.Body)
    log1.Check(err, "Cannot write file")

    err = f.Close()
    log1.Check(err, "Cannot close file")
}
```

Also, close the response body.

Comment: Thank you, that works great. Whats the reason for the difference when writing in server response format? Is it something to do with the write docs saying "Header, values for non-canonical keys will have unpredictable behavior"?

Comment: An HTTP response has a status line, headers, blank line and the body (possibly in some encoding).  The zip file is the body.  If you are not fammilar with the HTTP protcool, then page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages might be helpful .